# JQuery Mobile Styling Persists Into Page I Link To

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I am using a link from a page where I use `Jquery Mobile` to a page where I do not.  For some reason the `Jquery Mobile` styling persist onto the page that I link to `UNTIL` I refresh the page, in which case the page loads correctly.  I am pretty baffled at what might cause this issue, and I have tested it on both Firefox and Chrome.  I have tried disabling caching all with no luck.

Does anyone have an idea what could cause this?

Thanks in advance.

**hello_world.php:**

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="create2.php" data-icon="plus" class="ui-btn-left">Create</a>

</body>
</html>
```

**create2.php:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML> 
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body> 
<form>
Title: <input type="text" name="title" value="">
submit: <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try `<a href="create2.php" data-icon="plus" class="ui-btn-left" data-ajax="false">Create</a>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

refer this page to understand how jquerymobile's link works

put this attributes to anchor `rel="external", data-ajax="false"`

http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-links.html

> Links that point to other domains or that have rel="external",
>   data-ajax="false" or target attributes will not be loaded with Ajax

Default link behavior: Ajax

> To enable animated page transitions, all links that point to an
>   external page (ex. products.html) will be loaded via Ajax. To do this
>   unobtrusively, the framework parses the link's href to formulate an
>   Ajax request (Hijax) and displays the loading spinner. **All this is
>   done automatically by jQuery Mobile**.